# vtiger crm 5.4.0 custom module installation shows Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file

Tags: php, smarty, vtiger

I am in developing of a custom module in Vtiger CRM 5.4.0 .when i installing the newly developed  custom module at some server it shows a message  'Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file.' and i can't install the module.

Please help me rectify this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause for the vTiger error “Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file.” is the $root_directory value in the ‘config.inc.php’ is incorrect or misspelled.

In order to correct it follow the steps below:

```
Go to your vTigerCRM directory
Open “config.inc.php” with your favorite text editor
Go to line 86 and adjust $root_directory value to correct vTiger directory. Note, that the directory must end with /. It should look something like this – $root_directory = ‘/var/www/vtigercrm/’;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but, did the zip file that you imported into de CRM on other server actually copied the module folder?

The menssage 'Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file.' usually it's about privileges or the CRM cannot access the module folder because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things spring to mind:

Have you actually created the modules/Mytest directory and populated it? (Using the template in vtlib/ModuleDir/5.4.0 and then editing the filenames and class of Mytest.php)

Check the case of your module class definition, e.g. class Mytest vs. class Mytest

If you are using any version control or symlinks in the development of your modules/Mytest code then this can trigger the "Sorry! Attempt to access restricted file." messages.

In module setup script make sure you have added this lines.

```
$module->initTables(); 
$module->initWebservice();
```